# Generics - Invoking a parametrized constructor from another using this

Tags: java, generics

I have 2 constructors for a class. A parametrized constructor and a non parametrized one. The problem is I am unable to invoke the parametrized one from the other using this(...). However it works when I try the same invocation from somewhere else (say a main method)

Here is the code

```
package com.test.generics;

    public class Key<T> {

        private T t;

        public Key(T t){
            this.t = t;
        }

        public T getKey(){
            return t;
        }
    }
```

And then

```
package com.test.generics;

    public class KeyValueObject<T> {
        private String value;
        private Key<T> key;

        public KeyValueObject(Key<T> k){
            key = k;
            value = "-1";
        }

        public KeyValueObject(String keyString){
            this(new Key<String>(keyString)); //Here is the problem, this says the Constructor KeyValueObject<T>(Key<String> k) is undefined
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Key<String> keyStr = new Key<String>("x");
            KeyValueObject<String> keyValObj = new KeyValueObject<String>(keyStr); //I try the same thing from main method and it works.
        }
    }
```

Why does the compiler say  "Constructor KeyValueObject(Key k) is undefined". I do have a constructor KeyValueObject(Key k) defined.

Also in the main method, I am pretty much doing the same thing. If the overloaded constructor had worked, I could have used `new KeyValueObject("x")`

Comment: put `T` instead of `String` in your second constructor of `KeyValueObject`. As an alternative, you could add a factory method: `public static KeyValueObject<String> make(String value) { return new KeyValueObject<String>(value); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error is justified, because the code is not type safe.
To see why, suppose you wrote:

```
KeyValueObject<Integer> kv = new KeyValueObject("not an Integer");
```

The above would produce an attempt to invoke `KeyValueObject<Integer>(Key<Integer>)` with a `Key<String>` argument, which would obviously not be valid.

Answer (score 3):

The declared type for the `KeyValueObject<T>` attribute:

```
private Key<T> key;
```

is different from the type argument in your constructor call:

```
public KeyValueObject(String keyString){
    this(new Key<String>(keyString));
}
```

The constructor's generic type argument must match with the attribute's type:

```
public KeyValueObject(T t){
    this(new Key<T>(t));
}
```

Comment: Actually this is the part I don't get. Does not Key<T> mean, I can substitute T with any type ? I mean just look at the Key class by itself. It accepts a type param T and from the main method, I could do Key<String> k = new Key<>("str");

Comment: Thanks. I read Rogério's answer and now understand what you are saying. It makes sense. I marked the other answer as correct and have upvoted yours.

Answer (score 1):

As I already wrote in the comment, you can do this:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyValueObject<String> $0 = new KeyValueObject<>(new Key<>("x")); //old school
        KeyValueObject<String> $1 = new KeyValueObject<>("x"); //boxing constructor
        KeyValueObject<String> $2 = KeyValueObject.make("x"); //factory method
    }
}

class Key<T> {
    T key;

    public Key(T key){
        this.key = key;
    }

    public T getKey(){
        return key;
    }
}

class KeyValueObject<T> {
    //Solution 2: Create a factory method to handle the case `T` == `String`
    static KeyValueObject<String> make(String value) {
        return new KeyValueObject<>(value);
    }

    String value;
    Key<T> key;

    KeyValueObject(Key<T> key){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = "-1";
    }

    //Solution 1: Change `String` to `T`
    KeyValueObject(T key){
        this(new Key<>(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helps. I cannot use the factory method because I am migrating existing code to use generics. I will go with Solution 1. I have marked Rogerio's answer as correct because I understood it best with his example of what was wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

The type `Key<String>` does not necessarily match `Key<T>` so the error is valid. (an unsafe typecast would be possible thought)

consider implementing a factory method like this:

```
public static KeyValueObject<String> createKeyValueObject(final String keyString) {
    return new KeyValueObject<String>(new Key<String>(keyString));
}
```

or for better use of the generic possibilities:

```
public KeyValueObject(T k) {
    this(new Key<T>(k));
}
```